# iphone app crashes when a map view is added

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I'm trying to add an MKMapView to my app, and my app crashes as soon as that view that contains it loads. I even tried creating a new project, and simply adding the map view without writing a single line of code and it crashes also.

Any ideas what's the cause of that?

the call stack I get in the debugger is as follows:

```
#0  0x916a1132 in __kill
#1  0x916a1124 in kill$UNIX2003
#2  0x917338e5 in raise
#3  0x9174999c in abort
#4  0x93f65fda in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler
#5  0x02392333 in _objc_terminate
#6  0x93f6417a in __cxxabiv1::__terminate
#7  0x93f641ba in std::terminate
#8  0x93f642b8 in __cxa_throw
#9  0x02392481 in objc_exception_throw
#10 0x02556238 in +[NSException raise:format:arguments:]
#11 0x025561aa in +[NSException raise:format:]
#12 0x000155eb in _decodeObjectBinary
#13 0x0001646d in -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
#14 0x00016a9c in -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:]
#15 0x0001569c in _decodeObjectBinary
#16 0x00014809 in _decodeObject
#17 0x002e5a3f in -[UIView initWithCoder:]
#18 0x002d2af0 in -[UIWindow initWithCoder:]
#19 0x0001569c in _decodeObjectBinary
#20 0x00014809 in _decodeObject
#21 0x004a4d77 in -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
#22 0x0001569c in _decodeObjectBinary
#23 0x0001646d in -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
#24 0x00016a9c in -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:]
#25 0x0001569c in _decodeObjectBinary
#26 0x00014809 in _decodeObject
#27 0x004a4034 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
#28 0x004a5eb5 in -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:]
#29 0x002b1402 in -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile]
#30 0x002b231c in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
#31 0x002bc3ec in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
#32 0x002b4b3c in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
#33 0x002b99bf in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#34 0x02d5d822 in PurpleEventCallback
#35 0x0257eff4 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#36 0x024df807 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
#37 0x024dca93 in __CFRunLoopRun
#38 0x024dc350 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#39 0x024dc271 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#40 0x002b1c6d in -[UIApplication _run]
#41 0x002bdaf2 in UIApplicationMain
#42 0x00002774 in main at main.m:14
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Any crash description in console?

Comment: Debugging code is very difficult without seeing the code.

Comment: there is no code whatsoever! (other than the code generated when creating a window-based app)

Comment: quick update though - I do get an exception with the following reason: "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MKMapView)"

Comment: Did you add the right Frameworks? And please show us the code where you add the MapView...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might have missed including the `MapKit` framework.

Comment: This is what it will be. Had the same issue a few days ago on a new project and it drove me round the bend for a while until the penny dropped!

Comment: yup, you're right, I actually just saw this link: http://cs491f09.wordpress.com/2009/10/30/assignment-6-adding-the-mapkit-framework/
followed the instructions there, and it works - thanks!

Comment: I just had the exact same problem, but I found this link (from Apple) to be more useful: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1